# How can I extract the last word from each row of a pyramid?

Tags: python, sorting

My function decode() needs to read the text from a .txt file, arrange the number-word pairs in numerical order in the shape of a triangle, and return a string of the last words on each row.

I have successfully arranged the pairs, but when I try to isolate the last words on each row it prints all of the words into the string.

```
txt_file = ['3 love', '6 computers', '2 dogs', '4 cats', '1 I', '5 you']
def decode():
    sorted_file = sorted(txt_file)

    row = 0
    last_words_string = ''

    for i in range(len(sorted_file)):
        for j in range (0, i + 1):
            if row >= len(sorted_file):
                break
            pairs = sorted_file[row].split()
            last_word = pairs[-1]
            last_words_string += last_word + ' '
            row += 1
            print(pairs, end=' ')
        print()
    print(last_words_string)

decode()
```

Here is my current output:

```
['1', 'I']
['2', 'dogs'] ['3', 'love']
['4', 'cats'] ['5', 'you'] ['6', 'computers']



I dogs love cats you computers
```

But I need it to say "I love computers".
Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: You could unindent `last_words_string += last_word + ' '` and move it right before or after `print()`, so that it's executed only at the end of the inner for loop; the very last word will be repeated though, because the outer loop is too long; devise a workaround (some test, or replace the outer for loop with a while loop)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to produce a series of accumulated sums of an incremental counter as an index:

```
from itertools import accumulate, count

txt_file = ['3 love', '6 computers', '2 dogs', '4 cats', '1 I', '5 you']
sorted_file = sorted(map(str.split, txt_file), key=lambda t: int(t[0]))
output = []
for i in accumulate(count(1)):
    if i > len(sorted_file):
        break
    output.append(sorted_file[i - 1][1])
print(*output)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/OFxLBW

or to do it without using `itertools`:

```
txt_file = ['3 love', '6 computers', '2 dogs', '4 cats', '1 I', '5 you']
sorted_file = sorted(map(str.split, txt_file), key=lambda t: int(t[0]))
output = []
count = i = 1
while i <= len(sorted_file):
    output.append(sorted_file[i - 1][1])
    count += 1
    i += count
print(*output)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/eKwBpZ

Furthermore, if the numbers in the text file are all consecutive like they are in the question, you don't have to waste time sorting the entries at all, but instead map the numbers to the words with a dict, so that the overall time complexity can be reduced to *O(n)*:

```
txt_file = ['3 love', '6 computers', '2 dogs', '4 cats', '1 I', '5 you']
words = dict(map(str.split, txt_file))
output = []
count = i = 1
while i <= len(words):
    output.append(words[str(i)])
    count += 1
    i += count
print(*output)
```

This outputs:

```
I love computers
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/1IyN6C

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to mention I cannot import any libraries. :(

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution without a library then.

Answer (score 2):

It is right that the input needs to be sorted, but just calling `sorted` will sort the input alphabetically, and so '10 word' would be sorted before '9 word'. You really need to get the numerical value of that number and sort by *that*.

It is fine to define a function `decode` for the logic, but then define a parameter for the input, and don't call `print` inside the function, but *return* the output. It is up to the caller to print it.

Here is one of the many ways to do it:

```
def decode(txt_file):
    width = 1  # number of items on the same line in the triangle
    last = 0 # index of the last item on the current line in the triangle
    return  " ".join(
        word
        for i, (_, word) in enumerate(
            sorted((int(a), b) for a, b in map(str.split, txt_file))
        )
        if i == last and (last := last + (width := width + 1))
    )

# Example run
txt_file = ['3 love', '6 computers', '2 dogs', '4 cats', '1 I', '5 you']
print(decode(txt_file))
```

The second part of the `and` expression only gets evaluated when the first part was true, i.e. when the last word on the current line was found. In that case the next line is identified, which has a width that is one more. That width gets added so we now have the index of the next "last" word.

Every item in the list needs to be visited, but to avoid a second visit in the final loop:

```
def decode(txt_file):
    ordered = sorted((int(a), b) for a, b in map(str.split, txt_file))
    width = 1  # number of items on the same line in the triangle
    last = 0 # index of the last item on the current line in the triangle
    words = []
    while last < len(ordered):
        words.append(ordered[last][1])
        width += 1
        last += width
    return  " ".join(words)

# Example run
txt_file = ['3 love', '6 computers', '2 dogs', '4 cats', '1 I', '5 you']
print(decode(txt_file))
```

Anyhow, the bottleneck for large inputs will be the sorting, not that loop: the time complexity is O(log).

Comment: Just as a side note: the `natsort` module (https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) can be used to sort stringified numbers.

Comment: Note that for larger numbers this approach can be quite inefficient, unnecessarily generating all the non-triangular numbers and tuples only to be discarded with a filter.

Comment: @blhsing, it is not making it less efficient, since the sort already has to go through all the non-triangular numbers. The time complexity is still determined by the sort operation, which for huge inputs will be the bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, but unnecessary overhead is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes I agree that what is unnecessary is unnecessary ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The words you're trying to get are on 1-based indices of [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), where if *n* is the *m*-th triangular number, then *n* = *m* (*m* + 1) / 2. Solving for *m* using the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula), we get:

*m* = (sqrt(8*n* + 1) - 1) / 2

So we can get number of terms of triangular numbers from the length of the input list, and iterate over the the terms to get the word at the index of the corresponding triangular number after normalizing Python's 0-based indices:

```
txt_file = ['3 love', '6 computers', '2 dogs', '4 cats', '1 I', '5 you']
sorted_file = sorted(map(str.split, txt_file), key=lambda t: int(t[0]))
print(*(
    sorted_file[(n + 1) * (n + 2) // 2 - 1][1]
    for n in range((isqrt(8 * len(sorted_file) + 1) - 1) // 2)
))
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/0CAVyK

or to do it without using `math.isqrt`:

```
txt_file = ['3 love', '6 computers', '2 dogs', '4 cats', '1 I', '5 you']
sorted_file = sorted(map(str.split, txt_file), key=lambda t: int(t[0]))
print(*(
    sorted_file[(n + 1) * (n + 2) // 2 - 1][1]
    for n in range(int((8 * len(sorted_file) + 1) ** .5 - 1) // 2)
))
```

This outputs:

```
I love computers
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/5MquXc

Answer (score 0):

Steps :
A. Sort the text file.
B. Format the sorted file so that each list has one number and one string.
C. Have an outer loop that will iterate the whole list.
D. Have an inner loop that will iterate only the number of needed lists for a certain pyramid row.
E. In the inner loop keep track of only the last list of the row so that the required words can be captured.

Here is the code that worked for me :

```
txt_file = ['3 love', '6 computers', '2 dogs', '4 cats', '1 I', '5 you']

def decode():
    formated_data = []
    ## Sort the txt_file
    sorted_data = sorted(txt_file)
    ## Split out each element
    for i in sorted_data:
        formated_data.append(i.split())
    ## Initialization
    count = 0
    j=0
    output = ''
    while j<= len(formated_data):
        count +=1
        for k in range(j,j+count):
            if k < len(formated_data):
                print(formated_data[k],end= " ")
            else:
                break
        try:
            output += formated_data[k][-1] + " "
        except:
            break
        j = k+1
        print()
    return output

result = decode()
print(result)
```

The output:

```
['1', 'I'] 
['2', 'dogs'] ['3', 'love']
['4', 'cats'] ['5', 'you'] ['6', 'computers']
I love computers
```

Also one note, In the first step when you are sorting the Txt file, the numbers in the lists are in string format, so if the list consists of more than 9 elements(lists) the sorting would be not according to the number. If you need the sorting in the order of the numbers which is the first element of each list then you need to convert it in int format first then sort.